# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'double

Tags: swift, swift3

I keep getting this binary operator error that "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'double' 
[image: Error image]

```
var listCount = imageNameList.count
var roll: Double = SUPCalculator.degrees(motion.attitude.roll)
if startDegree == 0.0 {
    self.startDegree = SUPCalculator.degrees(motion.attitude.roll)
}
var diff: Double = roll - startDegree
var diffChange: Double = diff / 50
// I get the error here 
var diffIndex = listCount * diffChange
```

Comment: rmmaddy, what do you think could be the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift is strongly typed and doesn't coerce implicitly. So you need an explicit type conversion:

```
var diffIndex: Double = Double(listCount) * diffChange
```

This is different from casting because **Int** is not a subclass of **Double**. What you are doing is asking for a completely new **Double** value to be built at runtime.

This is without type conversion. Here you get the error. See at the console. It says,

> overloads for '*' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Int, Int), (Double, Double)

So either you make both of them **Int** or both of them **Double**:

[image: without explicit type conversion]

This is from explicit conversion. See, here no error remains:

[image: with explicit type conversion]

Comment: I did the same thing for this

Comment: self.toIndex = Double(startIndex) - diffIndex

Comment: I got an error saying, a binary operator - cannot be applied to two double operands

Comment: See my edit with added screenshots. Hope this helps.